# How to Convert String into Time format?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, time-format

I have a varchar column in sql server 2005 which stores time as 1420 but I want this to be shown as 14:20 or 02:20 PM in report. Please help..

Comment: its doesn't point to my question, as i'm using sql server 2005 but Time function was introduced in sql 2008, secondly I have stored values in 1420 format.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (t VARCHAR(10))
INSERT @tbl
SELECT '1420' UNION
SELECT '1545'

SELECT LEFT(t, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(t, 2)
FROM @tbl
```

Output

```
14:20
15:45
```

Comment: You can improve this answer by adding support for times before 10AM: e.g. 815

Comment: @ShahidMehmood, please vote it up or/and mark it as answer if it helped you so others can get some benefits out of that.